# How to check before insert to table in sql in this example?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i want to insert in the table after check exist or not exist in table.
if exist no insert and if not exist insert.

```
INSERT INTO Database.[dbo].[TBL_AllProduct]
                   ([Product_Name]
                   ,[Product_URL])

SELECT  
      t.v.value('(span[2]/a/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Name],
      t.v.value('(span[2]/a/@href)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
 FROM @html.nodes('div/div') as t(v)
```

check `[name]` in `@html.nodes` if not exsit `value` of `[name]` in `column` `[product_name]` then insert into table. select from `@html.nodes`

`t(v)` contain any rows , not only 1 row.

exmaple for export `t(v)`

```
--------------
    NAME
--------------
    piter
    alex
    sony
    telephon
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: and if not exists do nothing at all or do an update then ?

Comment: if not exists do nothing .

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Name  Nvarchar(50)

SET @Name=t.v.value('(span[2]/a/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Name] FROM @html.nodes('div/div') as t(v)


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name FROM Database.[dbo].[TBL_AllProduct] WHERE Product_Name=@Name) BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO Database.[dbo].[TBL_AllProduct]
                       ([Product_Name]
                       ,[Product_URL])

    SELECT  
          t.v.value('(span[2]/a/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Name],
          t.v.value('(span[2]/a/@href)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
     FROM @html.nodes('div/div') as t(v)

END
```

Comment: check `[name]` in `@html.nodes` if not exsit `value` of `[name]` in `column` `[product_name]` then insert into table. select from `@html.nodes`